# Invite Facebook friends with Graph API to get permissios

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a feature for a website which should allow someone to invite their Facebook friends to my service. That invitation would actually be a Facebook Application requesting permission of a user id and an email.  If the person accepts the invitation he/she would be added to contact list of the person who sent the invite. The service is about sending messages and recommendations to each other. I have tried playing with Graph API, I've managed to make send dialog working but it's not very user friendly, especially because the message cannot be pre-filled from the custom form. Also, I've managed to pull all my Facebook friends by using taggable_friends API call however the ID that I get in that object cannot be used to pre fill the "to: " parameter in the send dialog which makes it kind of useless. So my question is is there a way to invite somebody to use my app and give me a permission to access their ID and public email address. I can provide the code if necessary.